# Email signature detection - what are some common phrases to sign off emails?

Tags: greetings, email

I am a developer on Speaking Email, an app that reads out email in any language.

I am working on our email signature detector and I'm looking for some examples of Japanese phrases that would be found in an email signature.

Specifically I am looking for things like "kind regards" (as used in English) that would be very uncommon to find at the beginning or middle but very commonly signify the end of an email.

I gather "thank you" is commonly used at the end of emails in Japanese but it is also just as common in the middle of an email, so it is not ideal. Are there any other common phrases to sign off an email?

I would like the Japanese characters as they are written in an email.